# Casting from undetermined subclass to superclass

Tags: java, inheritance

So in the following example I have an abstract super class with two subclasses. I want the method **someMethod** to return an object of type **otherclass** and then I will cast it to **someSuperClass**. How can I create a new instance of an object of the same type as **otherclass**? I would like to avoid having it be an abstract method and then defining it in each subclass.

```
public abstract class SomeSuperClass {
    public SomeSuperClass() {
    }

    public SomeSuperClass someMethod(SomeSuperClass otherClass) {
        return (SomeSuperClass) ????
    }
}

public class SomeSubClass extends SomeSuperClass {
    public SomeSubClass() {
        super();
    }
}

public class SomeOtherSubClass extends SomeSuperClass {
    public SomeOtherSubClass() {
        super();
    }
}
```

Edit:

**otherClass** is a parameter/object that is of type **SomeSubClass** or **SomeOtherSubClass**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly you can use the `Class` of the object to create a new instance of it using the `newInstance()` method.

```
public SomeSuperClass someMethod(SomeSuperClass otherClass) 
        throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    return otherClass.getClass().newInstance();
}
```

Here is the complete example I worked from:

```
public abstract class SomeSuperClass {

    public SomeSuperClass someMethod(SomeSuperClass otherClass) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        return otherClass.getClass().newInstance();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeSubClass subClass = new SomeSubClass();
        try {
            SomeSuperClass newClass = subClass.someMethod(subClass);
            System.out.println(newClass.getClass().getName());
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public SomeSuperClass someMethod(SomeSuperClass otherClass) {
    try {
        return (SomeSuperClass)otherClass.getClass().getConstructor().newInstance();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return null;
}
```

Something like this should work for you.